# error NoSuchElementException when reading an int in a file

Tags: java, error-handling, int

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PayrollDemo{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner("Output.txt");
        Employee employee = readEmployee(input);  // <------ error here
        input.useDelimiter("\t");
        while(input.hasNext())
        {
            readEmployee(input);
            printDetail(employee);
        }
        input.close();
    }

    public static Employee readEmployee(Scanner s) 
    {
        String name = s.next();
        int id = s.nextInt();     // <------ error here
        double hourlyPayRate = s.nextDouble();
        double hoursWorked = s.nextDouble();
        Employee emp = new Employee(name, id);
        emp.SethourlyPayRate(hourlyPayRate);
        emp.SethoursWorked(hoursWorked);
        return emp;
    }   

    public static void printDetail(Employee e)
    {
        System.out.printf(e.getName()+ "    " + e.getId()+ "    " + e.GethourlyPayRate()+ " " + e.GethoursWorked()+ "   " +e.GetGrossPay());
    }
}
```

My code does not read the int from the Scanner in returns a message: NoSuchElementException. And the error also point to the Employee employee readEmployee(input).

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `output.txt` file?

Comment: and are you sure that your file is correct?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have any elements available in your file while doing `s.nextInt()`

When you do `next()` calls on `Scanner` it is always better to check element is available or not, by using `hasNext()`.

Example:

```
if(s.hasNextInt())   //while (or) if or whatever you want to use.
{
 int id = s.nextInt(); 
}
```

Comment: @ogzd: when you want to continuous use while, otherwise if. It is based on requirment.

Answer (score 1):

Never read an input before checking for it's existence. Use `Scanner#hasNextXXX` methods before using `Scanner#nextXXX`. Also, whenever you use `Scanner.next()`, or `Scanner#nextInt` or `Scanner#nextDouble` methods, you are left with a newline character that is not read, so you need to consume that, using a blank call to `Scanner#next()`.

So, replace the first 4 lines of your `public static Employee readEmployee(Scanner s)` method to:

```
// Use conditional operator to test for any available input. 
// If no input is available, just give a default from your side.
String name = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
s.next();
int id = s.hasNextInt() ? s.nextInt(): 0;     // <------ error here
s.next();
double hourlyPayRate = s.hasNextDouble() ? s.nextDouble(): 0.0;
s.next();
double hoursWorked = s.hasNextDouble() ? s.nextDouble(): 0.0;
s.next();
```